# Given T test cases check if a given word is present in a string or not

Tags: c++, string

We have given a word, "hello" and we have to check if this word is present in a given string or not for a given number of test cases.
My code is below, but it is not working if I take testcase "t". Otherwise it is working fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int i;
int t,flag=0;

int main()
{
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string a;
        getline(cin,a);
        for (i=0;i<a.length(); i++)
        {
            if (a.substr(i,5) == "hello")
            {
                flag=1;
            }
            else
                flag=0;
        }

        if(flag==1)
            cout<<"yes";
        else
            cout<<"not";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

input:

2

hello how are you?

hellobaby how are you?

output:

yes

not

Comment: You can directly use a.find ("hello")  for exemple

Comment: `if (a.substr(i,3) == "hello")` .... "hello" has 5 letters. Also, you need to set `flag=0` before the `for` loop. Or `break` when you found a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix is to replace

```
if (a.substr(i,3) == "hello")
```

with

```
if (a.find("hello") != string::npos)
```

**UPDATE:**

I suppose you need to match according to words delimited by space (" "), hence I propose the use of tokens, here is the example code by editing from your original code:

```
while(t--)
{
    string a;
    size_t pos = 0;
    string token;
    getline(cin,a);

    while ((pos = a.find(" ")) != string::npos)
    {
        token = a.substr(0, pos);
        if (token == "hello")
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
            flag = 0;
        a.erase (0, pos+1);
    }

    if(flag==1)
        cout<<"yes";
    else
        cout<<"not";
}
```

Additionally, I suggest you use `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore(100, '\n')` after `cin>>t` to clear the input buffer before reading a new string for testing.

Comment: if I use  this  if (a.find("hello") != string::npos) is will say yes for "hellobaby" also but I only want to print yes for "hello" word only.

Comment: Sry I don’t quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you please include some example input and desired output of the program. If you’re trying to search for exact match, I don’t see why you need a nested loop (or for that matter, substr)